# Localized XIB labels

Tags: iphone, localization, xib, localizable.strings

I took a look in different post and articles, and of course the apple documentation, usually enough for localization purposes.

But, I'm a newbie using IB.

In order to localize the XIB files, I know you can create one version for each language ... but anybody knows if is posible to manage from the UIViewController.

I prefer to manage the localization using the .strings file against to create different XIB files for every new language.

Could we retrieve the UILabel from the XIB file in the UIViewController (viewDidLoad)?

Thanks for your time,

Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't alter a XIB file but by the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the `UILabel` if it was part of the `XIB` file that the view controller loaded will already be part of the view hierarchy. Unless you've directly set an `IBOutlet` for the `UILabel` instance, you will have to search through the view hierarchy for a specific marker like a `tag` perhaps. Once you get the label, it should be a direct assignment of the localized string.

```
label.text = NSLocalizedString(.., ..);
```

Comment: I saw a previous answer with exactly the solution. 

http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-for-beginners-part-2-memory-and-controllers/

Although I've other problem ... I'm developing with the last version of XCODE and seams there is a problem to clean the nib generated files ... 

I have been changed the XIB content, but when the app runs on the simulator I always see the previous version :SSS

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you saying that although you are doing this, you are seeing the same content? Have you tried cleaning your build and [`derived data`](http://programmersweb.blogspot.com/2011/05/clearing-xcode-4s-derived-data.html) too.

Comment: I tried with Command + Shift + K and with Alt + Command + Shift + K with the same result :SS. I additionally remove the derived data ... but don't succeed.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell what's the problem with the info at hand. If only I could look at the project, I can help further. One more thing, have you changed your locale through the settings?

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your time. The problem was in one of the test i did, I configurate the xib as a localized file and, although i remove the versions Xcode store in my en.lproj folder the last version of my xib file. I move to the main folder and works!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but can we just subclass UILabel and overload the

```
- (void) setText:(NSString*) theString
```

method to

```
- (void) setText:(NSString*) theString
{
    [super setText: NSLocalizedString (theSrting);
}
```

Or something like this ?